# Wanting to generate auto unique ID on Google Form using the Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

im an intern and my supervisor ask me to add ID on company existing GForm for client and i have problem where the Apps Script said TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
_onFormSubmit   @ Code.gs:7

```
function _onFormSubmit(e) {
  const { rowStart } = e.range **This is the Code.gs:7**
  var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getFormUrl();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(url);
  var response = form.getResponses().pop();
  var url = form.getPublishedUrl();
  const editUrl = response.getEditResponseUrl()
  var responseId = response.getId();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h53k6.jpg)

Comment: From your error message of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined`, I'm worried that you might have run the script without giving the event object by directly running the script with the script editor. If my understanding is correct, how about executing the script by the trigger (in your situation, it's OnSubmit trigger.)?

Comment: Trigger the function using the form submit event to have a value on the event parameter. If you run it manually in the editor, it wont return any value that's why you encounter an undefined.